# how to pause the activity when the popup phone call dialog is answered?

Tags: java, android, mobile, samsung-mobile

The Samsung phone can call answer the the phone call at the popup dialog, but it don't fire the onPause() method, so the recording audio can't stop, so how to get the event/trigger if phone call is answered

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Manage your player controler on audio focus change

```
@Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
            switch (focusChange) {
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                    if (mPlayOnAudioFocus && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        play();
                    }
                    mPlayOnAudioFocus = false;
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                    //  setVolume(MEDIA_VOLUME_DUCK);
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                    try {
                        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mPlayOnAudioFocus = true;
                            pausePlayer();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                    mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
                    mPlayOnAudioFocus = false;
                    pausePlayer();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

For complete example check [Example](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-MediaBrowserService/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/mediasession/service/PlayerAdapter.java)